# Как изменять текст label чтобы происходило инкрементирование?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Не совсем могу понять как мне изменить text у label для того чтобы при нажатии на кнопку - происходила прибавка числа к переменной. В общем чтобы при нажатии на кнопку у меня label с id: score_score становился бы 1,2,3 и т.д, зависящее от нажатия кликов. Буду очень благодарен за пояснение решения проблемы.

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout


class kv(MDFloatLayout):

    def click(self):
        self.score_score.text = '' += 1  # ????
        return


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('Container.kv')
        return kv()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

**kv.kv**

```
<kv>:
    score_text: score_text
    score_score: score_score
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        FitImage:
            size_hint_y: 0.5
            source: 'images/background.jpeg'

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Clicker'
            font_size: 40
            color: [1,0,1,1]
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            id: score_text

            text: 'Score:'
            font_size: 40
            color: [0,0,0,1]
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}

        Label:
            id: score_score
            text: ''
            font_size: 40
            color: [0,0,0,1]
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.6, 'center_y': 0.6}


    FloatLayout:
        MDIconButton:
            id: MDI_Button
            user_font_size: "64sp"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
            on_release:
                root.click()
```

Comment: ```
self.score_score.text = str(int(self.score_score.text) + 1)
```
Выдает ошибку. Мне нужно создать переменную, к которой я позже смогу обратиться. Но в методе это не сделать, тут нужно мейби глобальную переменную сделать? Я просто почему то не могу у ней обратиться.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вы хотите сделать, что-то вроде такого:

`self.score_score.text = str(int(self.score_score.text) + 1)`